# getElementsByTagName undefined return - is this a bug?

Tags: javascript, undefined, getelementsbytagname, fiddle

I googled my heart out on this one and looked at most of the AI suggestions after typing in the question, but did not find the answer.  I have this:

```
<script>
<!-- JS return all element values of one tag type -->
var tagValues = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
var numTags = tagValues.length;
var retMessage = "The values of all elements with tag name 'td' are: \n\n";
var counter;
for (counter = 0; counter < numTags; counter++) {
    retMessage = retMessage + document.getElementsByTagName("td")[counter].value + "\n";
}
alert(retMessage);
```

It returns undefined values for every element.  the script is below all the HTML.  I even tried an alternative (which is the way it should be written anyway) return line:

```
retMessage = retMessage + tagValues[counter].value + "\n";
```

the js fiddle also returns the same error.  is this so simple I can't spot the error?

[image: js fiddle returning undefined]

Comment: `.value` only works for input-like elements

Comment: thank you!  I was unaware of that.  i'm surprised that solution was no documented at least somewhere on the internet.  everything else I saw made things extremely complicated.  some solutions even suggested a move to jQuery!  that's really ridiculous.  thanks again.  =)

Comment: Sure it's documented. https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+get+text+from+element+javascript and many links on SO as well. `.value` does not exist on `HTMLElement.prototype`